# convert char back to integer

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I doing convertion I do following coding,

```
Dim stx As integer = &H82
```

I know usually the  in ASCii is 0x02, however in my case the actual data is only 7-bit and the MSB is always filled by a '1', that's why the =0x02 -> 0x82. And this causes the following trouble.

```
tx_buff = Chr(stx) 'put stx into buffer prepare to send out

'convert stx back to integer
rx_buff = Asc(Chr(stx))
```

'when convert it back, rx_buff is actually 0x3F instead of 0x82, I guess it is because Chr() function converts &H82 into UTF-16 coding which is BREAK PERMITTED HERE (U+0082), but when converts back, using Asc() it using ASCii table, 0x3F is ?(question mark).

My question is how to solve that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rx_buff = Hex(stx)

Comment: What are you trying to put in the Rx buffer?  Why are you converting from Integer to Char and back again??

Comment: @Grim because the feedback is actually echo back the cmd I send out. I just make an assumption that if the transmission is successful. the 0x82 is in the rx_buff and I want to show it in hex form.

Comment: What are the buffers then??  Just strings??

Comment: @Grim Yes, just strings.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve.  You should be storing your data as numbers (preferably Byte rather than Integer) and only converting it to String/Hex representation when you need to display it.  Converting using `Chr/Asc` just causes trouble - as you've discovered.

Comment: @Grim Please advise. Let's say the cmd I am trying to send out is like <STX><J><1><2><3><4><ETX>, the feedback is just echo it back. <J><1><2><3><4> is from a text box as a string. so I need to convert J1234 into bytes and store them into a byte array?

Comment: Please see my answer.  I still don't quite understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Are you saying that you have to set the MSB before sending the data?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, that's the protocol requirement. every byte, the MSB is a '1'.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how you might send data:

```
Option Infer On
Module Module1

    Const STX As Byte = &H2
    Const ETX As Byte = &H3

    Sub SendByte(b As Byte)
        ' set the msb before sending the byte
        ' code here to send (b OR &H80)
    End Sub

    Sub SendMessage(msgBytes() As Byte)
        ' assumes all messages to be sent start with STX and end with ETX
        SendByte(STX)
        For i = 0 To msgBytes.Length - 1
            SendByte(msgBytes(i))
        Next
        SendByte(ETX)

    End Sub

    Sub SendMessage(msg As String)
        ' For characters with the msb set, this will give &H3F -
        ' so don't use such characters.
        Dim bytesToSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
        SendMessage(bytesToSend)

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        ' if the data to send should be represented in ASCII
        Dim messageToSend = "J123"
        SendMessage(messageToSend)

        ' if the "J" should be sent as its ASCII representation but
        '  the following data should be bytes
        Dim bytesMessage() As Byte = {Asc("J"), 1, 2, 3}
        SendMessage(bytesMessage)

    End Sub

End Module
```

And when you receive the data, use

```
receivedByte = receivedByte And &H7F
```

to unset the msb.

Comment: @ClickRick Oops! Corrected.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you. I think the most hard part is at receive end. the msg sent out is <0x82><J><1><2><3><0x83><LRC>, I hope the receiver end can also show <0x82>...<LRC>, in the past I just use serialport.write(data), data as string. It's find even with 0x82, 0x83, but the receiver end, I use serialport.readexisting which return a string. I understand now that's not work, so I might use readbyte instead. Again thank you for your suggestion when send msg out.

Answer (score 0):

As per your definitions;

```
Dim stx As Byte = &H82   ' 7-bit encoded
Dim etx As Byte = &H83   ' ditto
```

I think you should be transmitting to ++whatever it is!++ using a `Byte` array;

```
Dim tx_buff() = {stx, &H1, &H2, &H3, etx}
```

When it comes back, again as a `Byte` array, it just needs translating to int/asc/hex or whatever to be displayed (for this example, I'm just reproducing the Tx buffer);

```
Dim rx_buff(4) As String

For vIndex = 0 To tx_Buff.Length - 1
    rx_buff(vIndex) = tx_Buff.ToString("X2")
Next

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", rx_Buff))
```

Note:  All untested!  Feel free to expand on your problem and I'll update this answer accordingly.